# How to build multiple one-to-many relations in Active Record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models like this:
Task has two relations with Student, started_by and finished_by, which are both one_to_many relations.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :started_by, class_name: Student, foreign_key: 'started_by_student_id'
    belongs_to :finished_by, class_name: Student, foreign_key: 'finished_by_student_id'
    attr_accessible :name, :id
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :id

has_many :started_tasks, class_name: Task
has_many :finished_tasks, class_name: Task
end
```

When I query like

```
Task.joins(:started_by).all()
```

or

```
Task.joins(:started_by).all()
```

the generated SQL looks good. But When I do:

```
Task.joins(:started_by, :finished_by).all()
```

The generated SQL looks weird:

```
  Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` INNER JOIN `students` ON `students`.`id` = `tasks`.`started_by_student_id` INNER JOIN `students` `finished_bies_tasks` ON `finished_bies_tasks`.`id` = `tasks`.`finished_by_student_id`
```

I don't know where this 'finished_bies_tasks' comes from, How should I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what causing issue,`:foreign_key` to task model,and or `Task.joins([:started_by, :finished_by])` or `Task.joins(:started_by).(:finished_by)` try this,

Comment: Is this a pluralisation issue on :started_by and :finished_by? What do the SQL tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Task.find :all, :joins => [: started_by, : finished_by]
```